# When editing User with Devise why does it pre-fill the new password field with the User's current password, and how to override

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, registration

Please forgive this relatively newbie question, but I could use some help.

I've installed the Devise Gem on my User model with only minor changes to the Devise views and no changes to the controller.  Still, I am having an issue that I can't solve.

The accounts/edit url (I've defined the routes using, 'devise_for :users, :path => "accounts"') brings up the user edit form as expected.  But, the field to insert a new password is pre-filled with the user's current password (with type = password, of course).  I don't want this field to be pre-filled with anything.  So, I'd like the field to be blank whenever the form is rendered.  I've tried the following change in the devise/registration/edit view, but it didn't replace the pre-filled password with a blank string, like I had hoped:

```
<p><span style = "font-weight:bold; padding:0"><%= f.label "New Password" %></span><br />
<%= f.password_field :password, :value => ""%>
  <i>(just leave this blank if you don't want to change your current password)</i></p>
```

I'm sure that there is an easy fix, but I just can't find it anywhere.  Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: See this answer. It prevents client side autocomplete also.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/34939348/1287329

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Give the input tag the attribute autocomplete= "off" and see if that helps.

```
<%= f.password_field :password, :autocomplete => 'off'  %>
```

http://blog.teksol.info/2005/11/16/prevent-field-autocompletion-in-rails-applications

Comment: This doesn't work for me.  It seems a client-side option to prevent the autocomplete on certain browser but this doesn't prevent Rails from pre-entering a value in the password field when it builds the form.

Answer (score 0):

not an easy way I'm afraid :(. I edited the user class removing the :validatable devise feature and added this by hand.

```
validates_presence_of :password, :if => :password_required?
validates_confirmation_of :password, :if => :password_required?
validates_length_of :password, :within => 6..30, :allow_blank => true, :if => :password_required?
```

and this method so the validation only runs when

```
def password_required?
    !persisted? || !password.nil? || !password_confirmation.nil?
end
```

and on the users_controller in the update method only updates the password if it is present

```
if params[:user][:password].blank?
  params[:user].delete(:password)
  params[:user].delete(:password_confirmation)
end
```

hope it helps.

Comment: just found this https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-edit-their-account-without-providing-a-password

Comment: Thanks @maurico, but I think that my problem is a little different than the one that you solve above.  It's not that I don't want the password field to be present in the edit form.  I just don't want the password field to be pre-filled in with the user's current password.  I'd rather have it be blank on rendering the form.  Can you think of a way to do this?  Thanks for the help!

Comment: you have to leave the passwords fields in the form and try the code of my answer.