# Autocomplete off For Password Field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a form for editing user details. When i select the form the password field already shows the password in its form field.. So when i just change the other things and then try to save the password also goes for updation..
How can i leave the password field blank..
This is so far what i have tried.. But no luck

```
<%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off", class: "form-control", placeholder: "Leave as blank if you don't want to change password", value: "" %>
```

Comment: Do you happen to use a browser plugin that autocompletes passwords by any chance? There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with your code itself.

Comment: @WToa haa.. this causes problem only in Google Chrome.. :(

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:** Previous hack no longer works on current Chrome.
Now, `autocomplete="new-password"` is usable.

Like this
`<input autocomplete="new-password" type="password" />`

=========== old answer ===========

Put this tag at first line of your form.

```
<input type="password" style="display:none;" />
```

I think this isn't so cool, but it prevents the autocomplete of password field.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the best way to fix this. It's a browser issue, but you must fix this from your view. Here is your solution with a little javascript. You should do this for both `password` and `password_confirmation`. Just add `readonly:"readonly", onfocus:"javascript: this.removeAttribute('readonly')"`

**Here is a real example that works:**

```
<%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: false, placeholder: "Leave it blank if you don't want to change your password", readonly:"readonly", onfocus:"javascript: this.removeAttribute('readonly')", class: "form-control" %>
```

You will have be creative with your css, if you need to. Basically the field is read only until it's clicked on (onfocus) with js you're removing the readonly attribute. So this way it's much more professional.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with your code.

Try clear your remember password in browser. This is because you remembered user at the time of login. Try clear cache and every other thing.

Answer (score -1):

Try following these steps:

Delete all your data

1. Click the Chrome menu Chrome menu on the browser toolbar.
2. Select Tools.
3. Select Clear browsing data.
4. In the dialog that appears, select "Empty the Cache"
5. Use the menu at the top to select the amount of data that you want
   to delete. Select beginning of time to delete everything.
6. Click Clear browsing data.

Taken and modified from: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95582?hl=en